# Marketing cloud - how to send a transactional SMS via API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, api, sms

I want to send an SMS after the user places an order.

I found this article: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/transactional-messaging-get-started.htm.

But, there are some things I don't understand:

1. Do I need to create one "definition" or create a "definition" for each send?
2. In the documentation of sending the SMS, I see this object:

```
"subscriptions": {
       "resubscribe": true
}
```

What is it used for? After all, we send a transactional SMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You only need to create one definition per message template. Each send would then use that definition. So you're not creating a new definition for every single contact.
2. I believe the example for transactional SMS is using a payload for the generic SMS triggered send as the parameter isn't listed in the documentation. It shouldn't be required for transactional SMS. But to answer your question it will resubscribe a contact as you're sending the message as opposed to having the contact manually opt-in to the keyword.

Comment: Thank you!! Do I need to create a new keyword for transactional?

Comment: I don't think it is a requirement, but it might be useful for separation of concerns almost similar to how you might have an entire business unit for transactional messaging.

Comment: Thank you! Where can I find the definition that I created in the UI?